# Unexpected trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

This the code I use to create a link:

```
<a href="http://www.ad_delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Delete</a>
```

But the result contains a slash before the query string:

```
<a href="http://www.ad_delete.php/?id=1">Delete</a>
                                 ^
                                 |
                                 Here
```

What gives?

Comment: And where does the "$row" variable get its value?

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM remax_ad";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: I feel like that's not possible. Are you sure you're looking at the right part of the code? What happens if you remove the PHP? What happens if you remove `?id=`? You need to play around with this a bit in a way that we can't.

Comment: OK.  I tried this instead of the php " <a href="http://www.ad_delete.php?id=23">Delete</a>" and it still rendered "<a href="http://www.ad_delete.php/?id=23">Delete</a>

Comment: How are you determining the output? You need to use *View Source*, not any DOM inspector (Chrome dev tools, Firebug, etc)

Comment: Is that link http://www.ad_delete.php you hard coded or printing by using any variables ?

Comment: A bug of this kind always gets me when I have a test output somewhere that I forgot about; the first line *shouldn't* produce the second, but without looking through all your code I can't say for sure.

Comment: Why did you put `.htaccess` tag? Do you have any rules there? If yes post them.

Comment: please use var_dump($row['id']);

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Are you sure your url is correct? AFAIK, It couldn't be http://www.ad_delete**.php**

it could either be www.ad_delete **.com**/foo.php

or /ad_delete.php

For both the later cases, appending url with ?id=$row works.

phpFiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/11m-3ja